# Regular Installer Menu After Flashing

Tags: server, system-installation, 22.04, raspberrypi

I want to give my Ubuntu Server 22.04 LTS on raspberry pi 400 a static IP. For some reason when I flash the OS the 01-network-manager-all.yaml is not created and when I create the file it crashes the OS and I need to reflash the micro SD card. I have set up ubuntu server on a laptop and when I first boot it I get a setup wizard and can set my static ip through that. When I flash my micro SD and put it in a raspberry pi however I do not get a setup wizard. Is there any way I can still boot to the wizard on a raspberry pi? I have tried RPI imager and balenaEtcher and both skip the setup wizard.